# What happens if you hit a rolling modifier when you have advantage?

Tags: gloomhaven

What happens if you hit a rolling modifier when you have advantage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have advantage, you draw two modifier cards.

Then:

- If none are rolling modifiers, you pick the better card.
- If one is a rolling modifier, you add its effect to the other card.
- If both are rolling modifiers, you continue to draw cards until a rolling
  modifier is not drawn, then you add together all drawn effects.

> *Source: Page 20 of the 2nd Edition Rulebook, Advantage and Disadvantage section*

Comment: To determine the better card in the situation where neither is a rolling modifier, consult the "Advantage/Disadvantage" section of the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1897763/official-faq-game-revs-1-and-2-no-rules-questions).

Comment: Its also worth noting that *literally everyone* thinks that Advantage and Rolling Modifiers resolve as written in a way that is having Advantage is *not better* than not having Advantage (for example: if you draw `Rolling +1` and a `Miss`, the *rules as written* say you miss). As such my table (and many others') draws stacks (so in this case, one stack with be `Rolling +1, Miss` and then *draw a third card* `-1`: The `-1` is better than the `Miss` so Advantage kicks in and that's the result; Disadvantage works the other way).